# SwiftUI: Embed textfield in text

Tags: text, textfield, swiftui

I would like to embed a textfield in a text ([see sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L0FPh.png)).

How do I solve this problem in SwiftUI? Is there a more elegant way in UIKit?

**Update**: As requested, my affords so far ([see result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kSLoH.png)):

```
struct Home: View {
    @State private var text: String = "amet"

    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Text("Lorem ipsum dolor sit")
            TextField("text", text: $text)
            Text(", consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you include your affords so far please?

Comment: Sure, i've updated my initial post.